# Add node CATEGORIES to vcard with perl module "vCard::AddressBook"

Tags: perl, addressbook, vcf-vcard

I do not find a possibility to add nodes like `CATEGORIES` or `ORG` to a vcard object when using the perl module **vCard::AddressBook** (https://metacpan.org/pod/vCard::AddressBook).

The output should look like this:

```
BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:4.0
...
N:Doe;John;;;
...
ORG:Organization_01;
CATEGORIES:Cat_01
...
END:VCARD
```

When I use the following code:

```
use vCard::AddressBook;
my $address_book = vCard::AddressBook->new();
my $vcard = $address_book->add_vcard;
$vcard->given_names(['John']);
$vcard->family_names(['Doe']);
$vcard->categories(['Cat_01']);  ## DOES NOT WORK
my $file = $address_book->as_file('file.vcf');
```

I get the following error:

```
Can't locate object method "categories" via package "vCard" at tmp2.pl line 6.
```

What is the best way to get other nodes like **CATEGORIES** in my vcard file?

BTW: RFC6350 defines it... https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6350#section-6.7.1

Comment: See also [this](https://github.com/ranguard/text-vcard/issues/63) issue

Comment: I suggest you look at the above issue and create a patch. The author is usually responsive. He hasn't looked after this much recently, but I'm sure if you email him after creating a PR he will either merge it or give you a COMAINT to deal with it.

Answer (score 2):

There is https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::vCard::Precisely which seems to be more compliant with RFC6350:

```
use Text::vCard::Precisely;
my $vcard = Text::vCard::Precisely->new( version => '4.0' );
$vcard->n(['John','Doe']);
$vcard->categories([qw/Cat_01 Cat_02 Cat_03/]);
print $vcard->as_string();
```

prints:

```
BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:4.0
N:John;Doe;;;
CATEGORIES:Cat_01,Cat_02,Cat_03
END:VCARD
```